# How does Semantic Scholar count influential citations?

Tags: bibliometrics

On Semantic Scholar, each author has a count of "Highly Influential Citations", see for example https://www.semanticscholar.org/author/Onur-Mutlu/1734461.

This information is also present in the API (field `influentialCitationCount`).

How are those "Highly Influential Citations" identified and counted?

Comment: The answer is available in the [FAQs on the SC website](https://www.semanticscholar.org/faq#influential-citations).

Answer (score 2):

Semantic Scholar's algorithm for counting "Highly Influential Citations" is described in this paper:

Identifying Meaningful Citations (Marco Valenzuela, Vu Ha, Oren Etzion)
https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Identifying-Meaningful-Citations-Valenzuela-Ha/1c7be3fc28296a97607d426f9168ad4836407e4b